# Is there a big.BitCount?

Tags: go, bitcount

Is there an already-written `BitCount` method for big.Int? There doesn't seem to be one in math/big.

Obviously I will write one myself if not - does anyone have one already written?

I want the number of set bits in the number. Like [Java BigInteger.bitCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitCount%28%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put one together myself - note that this does **not** take into account the sign of the number. This returns the bit count of the the raw bytes behind the `big.Int`.

```
// How many bits?
func BitCount(n big.Int) int {
    var count int = 0
    for _, b := range n.Bytes() {
        count += int(bitCounts[b])
    }
    return count
}

// The bit counts for each byte value (0 - 255).
var bitCounts = []int8{
    // Generated by Java BitCount of all values from 0 to 255
    0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
    1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
    1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
    2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
    2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5,  
    2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
    1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
    2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
    2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
    3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
    4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
    1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
    2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
    2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
    3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
    4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
    2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
    3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
    4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
    3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
    4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
    4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
    5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 8,
}
```

Comment: I think it would be faster if you used an `int8` here instead of `int`, you'll get more(4x?) cache hits.

Answer (score 6):

As already mentioned, for quick efficient raw access to the underlying bits of a `big.Int` you want to use [`big.Bits`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Bits).
Also, quicker than either an 8 bit lookup table or a simple loop is to use one of well know 64 bit methods of counting bits (aka [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight)).
Even faster, you could use an assembly implementation of `popcount` that uses a native [CPU instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight#Processor_support)¹.

Without using assembly, or catering to special cases where it's known there are few bits set, this is likely one of the faster/fastest Go implementations (it could be made faster on 32 bit machines by using `uint32` and adjusting the `popcount` function accordingly):

```
func BitCount(n *big.Int) int {
    count := 0
    for _, v := range n.Bits() {
        count += popcount(uint64(v))
    }
    return count
}

// Straight and simple C to Go translation from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight
func popcount(x uint64) int {
    const (
        m1  = 0x5555555555555555 //binary: 0101...
        m2  = 0x3333333333333333 //binary: 00110011..
        m4  = 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f //binary:  4 zeros,  4 ones ...
        h01 = 0x0101010101010101 //the sum of 256 to the power of 0,1,2,3...
    )
    x -= (x >> 1) & m1             //put count of each 2 bits into those 2 bits
    x = (x & m2) + ((x >> 2) & m2) //put count of each 4 bits into those 4 bits
    x = (x + (x >> 4)) & m4        //put count of each 8 bits into those 8 bits
    return int((x * h01) >> 56)    //returns left 8 bits of x + (x<<8) + (x<<16) + (x<<24) + ...
}
```

Benchmarks and comparisons of this and other implementations presented here is available in full on [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/dchapes/64d38931d011a7c9a3c9).

¹ Such as the [one added in Go1.9](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/math/bits/#OnesCount64); the updated gist shows it is ~3× faster than the previous best I had.

Answer (score 5):

You can use now (as of Go 1.9) the [`math/bits`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits) library that implements some useful functions that deal with bit-related computations. Concretely, you can iterate through the result of [`big.Int.Bits`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Bits) and call the [`bits.OnesCount`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits/#OnesCount) function.

Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "math/bits"
)

func BitCount(z *big.Int) int {
    var count int
    for _, x := range z.Bits() {
        count += bits.OnesCount(uint(x))
    }
    return count
}

func PrintBinary(z *big.Int) {
    for _, x := range z.Bits() {
        fmt.Printf("%064b\n", x)
    }
}

func main() {
    a := big.NewInt(1 << 60 - 1)
    b := big.NewInt(1 << 61 - 1)
    c := big.NewInt(0)
    c = c.Mul(a, b)

    fmt.Println("Value in binary format:")
    PrintBinary(c)
    fmt.Println("BitCount:", BitCount(c))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, the following solution is simpler and faster than the original solution provided here:

```
func BitCountFast(z *big.Int) int {
    var count int
    for _, x := range z.Bits() {
            for x != 0 {
                    x &= x-1
                    count++
            }
    }
    return count
}
```

It outperforms the original solution by 5x on my machine:

```
BenchmarkBitCountFast-4 100000000           19.5 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkBitCountOrig-4 20000000            96.1 ns/op        16 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

Comment: One of the reasons this is faster is that [`Bits`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Bits) returns raw access to an underlying `[]big.Word` whereas [`Bytes`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Bytes) allocates a new `[]byte`. Also note that the outer `for` loop here can be made faster using standard 32 or 64 bit ops to calculate the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) of each `big.Word` (just a `uintptr`) and removing the nested loop. E.g. See [this gist comparison and benchmark](https://gist.github.com/dchapes/64d38931d011a7c9a3c9).

Comment: (note I've turned my previous comment into [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32702348/55504))

Comment: Another reason my code was faster is sparse bit sets used in benchmarks :) Your solution is faster with dense bit sets.